# ASP.NET Web.config issue with MagicAjax and Rewrite Rules

Tags: asp.net, ajax, wordpress, url-rewriting

Hey, I have the following rules in webconfig for my ASP.NET website which also contains several sections which are controlled in wordpress.

```
            <rules>
            <rule name="RedirectFinancial" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^orgprofile/financial\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^name=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/financial" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteFinancial" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/financial/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="orgprofile/financial.aspx?name={R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectGovernance" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^orgprofile/governance\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/governance" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteGovernance" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/governance/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="orgprofile/governance.aspx?name={R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectOverview" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^orgprofile/overv\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^name=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteOverview" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="orgprofile/overv.aspx?name={R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectPurpose" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^orgprofile/purpose\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^name=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/purpose" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewritePurpose" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/purpose/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="orgprofile/purpose.aspx?name={R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RedirectActivities" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^orgprofile/activities\.aspx$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^POST$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^name=([^=&amp;]+)$" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}/activities" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteActivities" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([^/]+)/activities/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="orgprofile/activities.aspx?name={R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="RewriteWordPress" patternSyntax="ECMAScript">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="\.axd$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{URL}" pattern="view.aspx$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^([^/]+)/financial/?$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^([^/]+)/governance/?$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^([^/]+)/?$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^([^/]+)/purpose/?$" negate="true" />
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" pattern="^([^/]+)/activities/?$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <serverVariables />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
```

The problem with magicajax when I add the above Rules is that my magicajax uploader doesnt work as intended anymore and when I click on the upload button it causes a page refresh where as before it would come up automatic.

Any Ideas how I can get around this ?

EDIT :  The problem seems to be overview rewrite rule

My friendly urls look like this

http://hostname/foldername/companyname    <--- overview

http://hostname/foldername/companyname/purpose  <---- i.e purpose rewrite rule

Comment: Ok so the problem was that one of the rewrite rules was stopping my .axd files from working so I had to add a condition to the rewrite rules as follows 

{URL} Does Not Match Pattern \.axd$

Comment: Thanks for this Q & A. It helped me figure out the problem.